# DateTimeFormatter works for most of the months

Tags: java

I am trying to parse my date it works for most of the months but for some reason, it doesn't work for April but on the other hand, it works for juin

### My code :

```
Locale locale = Locale.FRANCE;
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("dd MMM yyyy (HH:mm)").toFormatter(locale);
LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(, dateTimeFormatter);
LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(, dateTimeFormatter);
if(dateTime1.compareTo(dateTime2) < 0) {
    System.out.println("true");
} else {
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

### My error :

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01 avril 2021 (09:40)' could not be parsed at index 3
```

Is there still something wrong with my pattern

### Other Types of months Values:

```
19 déc. 2019 (21:15)
10 févr. 2020 (07:58)
```

Comment: Does it work for "févr?"

Comment: Are you trying to parse the short form of months or the full name of months? The short form of "avril" is "avr.".

Comment: @ThomasHerondale yes it does

Comment: @Sweeper the probleme i have is that some are short form but if they have less than 6 letters they dont take short form

Comment: @Michael i added the whole code for this part

Comment: I don't know french, but would I work if you add another pattern for the full-month-name like .appendPattern("dd MMMM yyyy (HH:mm)") ?

Comment: if i do this i need to control every value i get to see if it a full month name or a shot format one @TomStroemer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple optional sections for DateTimeFormatter. Keep in mind that with this configuration also "" or "01 avril 2021 (09:40)01 avr. 2021 (09:40)" would be valid (thanks to @Michael for the clarification).

```
public class FormatTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("01 avril 2021 (09:40)");
        test("01 avr. 2021 (09:40)");
        test("19 déc. 2019 (21:15)");
        test("19 décembre 2019 (21:15)");
        test("10 févr. 2020 (07:58)");
    }

    private static void test(String value) {
        Locale locale = Locale.FRANCE;
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("[dd MMMM yyyy (HH:mm)][dd MMM yyyy (HH:mm)]").toFormatter(locale);
        LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(value, dateTimeFormatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not "defining multiple formats", you are defining two optional sections. This can have undesirable implications, for example `dateTimeFormatter.parse("")` will succeed, because both sections are optional. Likewise `01 avril 2021 (09:40)01 avr. 2021 (09:40)` is a valid input

Comment: @Michael Thanks. I added this as clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your current pattern only works for parsing those dates when the short form of the month is the same as the long form. The short form of 'juin' is the same as the long form because it's already a short word; it doesn't need to be shortened further.

The short form of 'avril' is 'avr'. The parser is currently expecting the latter.

You need to change your pattern to use the long form if you want to parse full words. To use the long form in a pattern, use 4 Ms rather than 3: `dd MMMM yyyy (HH:mm)`

If the format of the month is variable then you can write your own logic around the formatter. It's not entirely clear to me what format you actually expect but this should give you the general idea:

```
String input = // whatever
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
if (tokens.length != 4) throw new RuntimeException("Invalid format");
String monthToken = tokens[1];
if (monthToken.length() > 4) {
    // parse with full month
}
else {
    // parse with short month
}
```

Comment: Can i override "LocalDateTime.parse(, dateTimeFormatter);" and add the comparing part in her ?

Comment: @Yan Override it? Like with inheritance? No. It's a final class

Comment: so i am forced to create another fucntion if i dont wanna add these +10 lignes of code for every time i call her

Comment: You are "*forced to create another function*" either way. You are either creating a function that overrides the existing one, or creating a function that *wraps* the existing one. In both cases, you've written one function, it's just a matter of where you place it. Anyway, [inheritance sucks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260343/why-is-inheritance-generally-viewed-as-a-bad-thing-by-oop-proponents) and you should not be actively looking for opportunities to use it; you should use it as infrequently as possible.

Comment: can you compare a long format with a short format